# Keep commented text in SQL query when using Invoke-Sqlcmd in PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

For example, I have the following SQL query that I want to run in PowerShell:

```
select 
item1, --this is a comment
item2
from myTable
```

If I tried to run this query in PowerShell using Invoke-Sqlcmd, I get a syntax error because it some how can't parse the comment as a comment:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'select item1, --this is a comment item2 from myTable'
```

Is there a way to keep my query comments?

Comment: When you looked up other types of comment syntax in SQL Server, what did you find?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sqlserver-ps&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using PowerShell [here-strings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/)? e.g.:

```bsh
Invoke-SqlCmd -Query @"
select 
item1, --this is a comment
item2
from myTable
"@
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is a multi-line query and if you remove the commented text it's equivalent to:

```
select 
item1, 
item2
from myTable
```

but your second example is all on a single line and is equivalent to:

```
select item1,
```

which isn't valid sql, hence the error.

You can make it a valid multiline query using "here strings":

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -Query @"
select 
item1, --this is a comment
item2
from myTable
"@
```

or insert line breaks (`` `r`n ``) into your second version yourself:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'select`r`n item1, --this is a comment`r`n item2`r`n from myTable'
```

Here-strings are obviously prettier than escaped line breaks, but take your pick...

Comment: Is this a PowerShell version issue? I have no issue running multi-line commands  with -- comments using sqlcmd without here strings...

Comment: It's not a PowerShell version issue - you can run *multiline* commands fine. What you *can't* do is collapse multiple lines onto a *single* line if you have "--" comments in the middle because everything after the "--" is treated as part of the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use [here-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59147107/696808), you can use [block comment syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/slash-star-comment-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'select item1, /*this is a comment*/ item2 from myTable'
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use [here-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59147107/696808) or a [block comment syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/slash-star-comment-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
Simply quoting the query is enough to preserve the new lines:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -Query '
select 
item1, --this is a comment
item2
from myTable
'
```

<sub>*Note*: It is recommended to [use single quoted (here)strings](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/292) for this as they are almost twice as fast as double quoted (here)strings.</sub>